# How can I show data in a DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, oop

I've got an enum and a Foo class:

```
public enum Type
{
    Arithmetic, Fraction, ...
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(Type problemType, bool isCorrect)
    {
        ProblemType = problemType;
        IsCorrect = isCorrect;
    }

    public Type ProblemType
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public bool IsCorrect
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Then I have a Foo list, where it is classified by ProblemType:

```
    public void ShowGradesInDataGrid()
    {
        List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();
        list.Add(new Foo(Type.Arithmetic, true));
        list.Add(new Foo(Type.Fraction, true));
        list.Add(new Foo(Type.Arithmetic, false));
        list.Add(new Foo(Type.Arithmetic, true));
        list.Add(new Foo(Type.Fraction, false));
        list.Add(new Foo(Type.Arithmetic, false));

        List<List<Foo>> groupedLists = list.GroupBy(foo => foo.ProblemType)
                                          .OrderBy(group => group.Key)
                                          .Select(group => group.ToList())
                                          .ToList();

    }
```

I don't know how to show the grupedLists in a datagrid in WPF. I was trying to show the list at this way:

- PROBLEM TYPE 1 (Arithmetic)      <-- EXPANDER

  - |GREEN|RED|GREEN|RED|
- PROBLEM TYPE 2 (Fraction) <-- EXPANDER

  - |GREEN|RED|

Where I put Green and Red are rectangles with fill.

```
 if (IsCorrect)
     // put rectangle with fill green
 else
     // put rectangle with fill red
```

Well the color is a plus for me, I actually wnat to show the list classified in datagrid. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally-speaking, the problem doesn't seem to fit a DataGrid.  Grouping data isn't possible - and DataGrids show grids of data.  You can do formatting with bindings and cell styles, but you might want to consider create your own control / set of controls.  Is there a reason you want to use DataGrid?

Comment: Well, I was watching in WPF Tutorial: http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html#grouping

I can imagine, I'll be to convert the data in something like a collection, but I really don't know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are asking is something similar to [this](http://blog.smoura.com/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-part-iv-templatecolumns-and-row-grouping/), Search for *Grouping rows using ItemsControl.GroupStyle*. As far as rectangles are concerned, you might want to use data triggers. check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/GuidedTourWPF_4.aspx) out.

PS: both articles have data triggers in it, but the second one is better for understanding it.

Comment: Exactly, something like the first link what I'm trying to do